# Randomising Data in The Movie DB API

Tags: javascript, api, mobile, jquery-mobile, themoviedb-api

I am currently developing a Mobile App using the Movie DB API.

I have currently got the data pulling through but it's being hardcoded to bring up Spiderman from the Database.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have attached my code below :)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){
// $(document).ready(function(){
    console.info('hi');
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
        mode = 'search/movie?query=',
        movieName = '&query='+encodeURI('Spiderman'),
        key = '&api_key=7b0b1d8b1253e2bbfcd5602f76c52fdb';
    $.ajax({
        url: url + mode + key + movieName ,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.dir(result);
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){
    $('#movie-data').empty();
    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.id == movieInfo.id) {
            $('#movie-data').append('<li><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92'+row.poster_path+'"></li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Title: '+row.original_title+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Release date'+row.release_date+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.vote_average+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('vclick', '#movie-list li a', function(){
    movieInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
});

var movieInfo = {
    id : null,
    result : null
}

var ajax = {
    parseJSONP:function(result){
        movieInfo.result = result.results;
        $.each(result.results, function(i, row) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92'+row.poster_path+'"/><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>')
    })
    }
}
```

Regards

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Spiderman is being hardcoded into the Url here, so you need to obtain the search string, save it in a variable and replace the hardcoded spiderman:

```
  var searchString = 'your_search_string'
  var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie?query=',
    movieName = '&query='+encodeURI(searchString),
    key = '&api_key=7b0b1d8b1253e2bbfcd5602f76c52fdb';
```

Also if you just want a list of movies not necessarily related to a search string you can try the discover endpoint of Movie DB API `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie`.
[Documentation link](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie-discover)